# Create a sizeless array in bash

Tags: bash

I am just starting to learn bash and I want to create a sizeless array but I could not.
How can I define an array without defining the size?

Comment: You don't declare array sizes in `bash`.

Comment: Could you explain *why* you would want a sizeless array? In fact, since the default way of declaring an array as explained by @Socowi *is* without a size, what is the underlying question?

Answer (score 3):

Arrays in bash are not like arrays in C or Java. They are more like dictionaries. From the perspective of a Java developer, a bash array would be something like `Map<Integer, String>`. Bash arrays ...

- *don't* have a fixed size.
- can grow and shrink as needed.
- can even be sparse. That is you can have `array[0]` and `array[2]` without having an `array[1]`.
  Therefore, the last entry in an array of size `${#array}` is not necessarily `array[${#array}]`.

To define an initially empty array, use `declare -a name` or `name=()`. There is no way to specify the size. The size is only defined by the content and may change throughout your script.